# integration question very short help me?>

Tags: integration

I am not sure if i should solve this with integration by partial fracions
So,Im in the middle of solving an exercise but I got here $-u^3/(2+2u^2) $..

how to integrate this by partial fraction?

how do I solve its integral in the shortest way? or is INTEGRATION BY PARTIAL FRACTIONS the only way?

by the way,can you show me a way to solve this type of integrals very fast?

Comment: Can you state your entire question? That might be good for context.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $$\frac{u^3}{1+u^2}=u-\frac{u}{1+u^2}$$

No partial fractions are needed, and you should discover this right away if you attempt to use them, since you must first divide out to get a fraction whose numerator has lower degree than its denominator.

Comment: But OP wanted partial fractions too. Still +1 for the fast part.

Comment: @exploringnet: That **is** what happens when you use partial fractions!

Comment: @exploringnet: the OP also stated that (s)he wasn't sure about partial fractions.  Brian's hint is sufficient in that spirit.